# iOS 4.3 AudioQueuePause vs home button

Tags: ios, audioqueue

I use `AudioQueue` to play sound in my game. There are two sound objects: looped `music` and non-looped `sfx`. The problem that I observe is as follows:

1. The `music` is started.
2. The `sfx` is started.
3. The `sfx` is paused (using `AudioQueuePause`)
4. The game goes to background by Home Button.
5. I get `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` and the `music` is paused (using `AudioQueuePause`).
6. I return to my app from iPad menu.
7. I get `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and the `music` is unpaused (using `AudioQueueStart`).
8. Note that I did not unpause `sfx`. In spite of that, it resumes and I can hear it!

I can only reproduce it on iPad with iOS 4.3 when going to background by Home Button. If I use Sleep/Wake button instead of Home, it works perfectly.

So it seems that the system somehow resumes all audio queues : even explicitly paused ones.
Any thoughts?